# FileDialog crash when bottom 4GB full

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, crash, 64-bit

in order to catch pointer truncation bugs in 64 bits, I added the code snippet mentioned [here](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/64-bit-made-easy/) that reserves the bottom 4GB of memory so allocs are above 32 bits.  In a MFC x64 test app, I call the reservation function first thing in InitInstance().  I then added a button that simply does:

```
CFileDialog dlg(TRUE);
dlg.DoModal();
```

Calling DoModal eventually crashes somewhere with a callstack in "no mans land":

```
>   000000018000163b()  
    0000000100000024()  
    0000000000000001()
```

This is not MFC specific since I get the same behavior with a .NET FileDialog.  I think it's something out of my hands since the actual fileDialog shows up briefly and then crashes.  Feels like a shell extension or something but I can't get where it's coming from since the call stack isn't helping - but I want to find out if there's anything I can do!

If I remove the special reservation function I don't get the crashes anymore.

Puzzled!

Comment: Well, it is working, you are catching pointer bugs.  Just not in your code.  Use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to disable shell extensions.

Comment: What happens if you try the same thing with `GetOpenFileName` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ? +Ton site web est down...

Comment: Can you check which module's address space it occurs in, or is the stack being smashed?

Comment: Yeah, I know it works (crashes)!  Thanks for the AutoRun utility, I didn't know it existed.  However, disabling all shell extensions still crashes.  As for the module, the call stack is completely smashed; what I have is what is in my original post

Comment: I'm curious if other people have the same behavior though I know  everyone's time is precious

Comment: More info: before I call DoModal, there's only 1 thread in my app (obviously).  When it crashes, there are 20 and it crashes in a thread called TppWorkerThread (there are a lot of those).  At that moment, my main thread is in WM_INITIDIALOG calling CallWindowProc

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to repro this crash. I created a 64-bit project, added the 4 GB reservation, and opened a file dialog within it. No crash.

Either my repro doesn't match yours, or there is something on your system that is different. You should post your project so that we can remove one of the variables.

Unfortunately I don't remember what a TppWorkerThread is.

Post your project -- all source files, resource files, .vcxproj files, and .sln files. Then we can investigate.

Comment: Bruce gives me an idea : are you sure there are no other DLL loaded in your process ? I know of many extensions that load themselves in the dialog, they could be the ones bringing it down.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on this issue, we found out that a shell extension installed by the 360 sdk causes the issue (xeshlext.dll)

Comment: My own follow-up.  We found an internal service that was conflicting with the 360 shell extension and caused the crash.  Upgrading to the latest version fixed everything.  Sorry for bothering you!